# how to save files in the data base with jquery-fileupload multiple

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use Jquery-fileupload blueimp and my question is how to save the files in my database? I have 8 files uploaded with the multiple upload, but I do not know how to save them in my database. can anyone help me please

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include relevant code to show your efforts and tell us how it's failing.

Comment: What language are you using server-side?  Simple method though is to walk through the folder afterwards and add the files (add a finished button linked to a new page, route or function to do that).  The Python Flask version I'm using has an /upload route called for each file as it uploads where you could do this as well.